# Как разобрать такой текст?

Tags: php

Как такой код разобрать на части, отдельными тегами или тп.

```
tovar|куртка||nal|111||beznal|222||price|333||dostavka|444||prod|Имя
```

Чтобы можно было вывести на страницу так

```
Товар: куртка
Наличные: 111
...
```

Comment: Самый лучший вариант: не хранить данные в таком ужасном виде...А хранить всё по-человечески, тогда и извращаться не придётся

Comment: Если хочется извращаться., то можно использовать https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: Пробовал так `echo $pieces[1]` один символ только выводится. По идее мне только нужны значения между `|` и `||`. В мануале ничего не понял. Можно ещё пример?

Comment: Почитай русскую версию мануала значит............ вначале разбиваешь строку по символу `||`, получишь массив........По получившемуся массиву бежишь циклом и разбиваешь каждый элемент по символу `|` и берёшь там уже 0 и 1 индексы

Comment: @steep, `Пробовал так echo $pieces[1] один символ только выводится` все правильно. в php строка это буквально и есть - массив из символов, и порядковый номер выводимого символа равен запрашиваемому индексу. а для того чего вы хотите нужно разбить строку на подстроки и уже подстроки выводить, как посоветовали выше. гляньте функции с префиксом str_*. кажется вам нужен `str_split()` или как то так... непомню уже. там их не миллион, быстро найдете нужную. **upd:** еще с префиксом `preg_*` гляньте, они тоже со строками работают

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Вашу задачу можно решить следующим способом:

Добавил комментарии.

```
$Str = 'tovar|куртка||nal|111||beznal|222||price|333||dostavka|444||prod|Имяv';
$t_name_a = ['tovar'=>'Товар','nal'=>'Наличные','beznal'=>'Безналичные','price'=> 'Стоимость','dostavka'=>'Доставка','prod'=>'Прод']; // Массив для перевода ключа в название
$t1 = explode('||',$Str); // Сначала разбиваем массив по ||
if($t1 and count($t1)>1){ // Если есть значение и их больше 1
    $Result_str = '';
    foreach ($t1 as $item){ // Для каждого элемента
        $N_n = explode('|',$item); // Разбиваем значение по |
        $n_name = (isset($t_name_a[$N_n[0]]))?$t_name_a[$N_n[0]]:''; // Проверяем первую часть в массиве перевода названия
        $n_val = (isset($N_n[1]) and !empty($N_n[1]))?$N_n[1]:''; // Если есть значение записываем
        $Result_str .= $n_name.': '.$n_val.'<br>'; // Добавляем в строку
    }
    print_r($Result_str); // Вывод строки
}
```

Вывод:

```
Товар: куртка
Наличные: 111
Безналичные: 222
Стоимость: 333
Доставка: 444
Прод: Имяv
```

Answer (score 0):

если без избыточных усложнений то

```
$str = "tovar|куртка||nal|111||beznal|222||price|333||dostavka|444||prod|Имя";
$data = explode('||', $str);
$result = [];
foreach ($data as $item) {
    [$key, $value] = explode('|', $item);
    $result[$key] = $value;
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Ну или старый трюк parse_str(str_replace(['||', '|'], ['&','='], $str), $result);